# Using Twitterizer to display the outbound tweets, not replies

Tags: c#, twitter, twitterizer

Ia m using twitterizer to diplay tweets on the website , but the issue its showing all the tweets ,i just want to show the tweets by user not the replies, the code i am using is:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {

            UserTimelineOptions options = new UserTimelineOptions();
            options.ScreenName = "XXXXX";

            TwitterStatusCollection tweets = TwitterTimeline.UserTimeline(options).ResponseObject;
            int counter = 0;
            string TwitterCode = "";     

            foreach (TwitterStatus thisStatus in tweets)
            {
                if (counter < 7)
                {
                    DateTime completeDate = thisStatus.CreatedDate;
                    string complete = completeDate.ToLongDateString();
                    TwitterCode += "<li><p ><a href=\"http://twitter.com/" + thisStatus.User.ScreenName + "\" target=\"_blank\" >" + Server.HtmlEncode(thisStatus.Text) + "<br/><span style=\"color:#E87D05;\">" +  complete + "</a></p></li>";
                    counter += 1;

                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }

            }

            ltlTweets.Text = TwitterCode;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        }
```

The above code works fine but i want to avoid the replies , how can i do that i have gone through documentation of twitteriser but couldnt find any solution for it , Anysuggestions or help will be appreciated 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `UserTimeLineOptions` object allows you to exclude retweets vie the `IncludeRetweets` property. Like so:

```
UserTimelineOptions options = new UserTimelineOptions()
{
    ScreenName = "myname",
    UserId = 123456789,
    IncludeRetweets = false,
    Count = 10,
};
```

The `UserId` helps the twitterAPI figure out that you are only requesting tweets made by that specific combination of `UserId` and `ScreenName` (i.e your account).

I'm not sure if it is completely necessary, but I also send an `OAuthTokens` object in with the request.

```
OAuthTokens token = new OAuthTokens()
{
    AccessToken = "xx",
    AccessTokenSecret = "xx",
    ConsumerKey = "xx",
    ConsumerSecret = "xx"
};
```

You would get hold of this information by creating an app under your twitter account at http://dev.twitter.com.

Then you would include the token in your call:

```
TwitterTimeline.UserTimeline(token, options);
```

Hope this helps =)